# What's the 'Macros Disabled' error popup called? And can I use that instead of msgbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this is a duplicate somewhere, but I really don't even know how to search for what I'm asking about, so I apologize in advance!

We've all encountered the "Macros are disabled" message bar.

[image: Notification]

I'm curious, 
A) What's that area called?
B) Is it possible to use that instead of a MsgBox to send the user a memo?

Comment: That's the Trust Center security warning and no it can't be used.

Comment: **[A]** It is called a "Yelow Security Bar" It is not only present in MS office but can be found in Internet Explorer as well. Sometimes it is referred to as Information Bar as well **[B]** No you cannot use it. However you can create a panel on the right hand side using VSTO Add-In which you can use to display messages.